# replace spaces with randam values

Tags: php, javascript

I have a paragraph ..i want to spaces are replace with some randam values.
for example

$string="Kapa dim nen ma sibilol sebire rola lunie. Ifosamac rapieco him oku, vimeror eralerie puredus elacecos tusorop gobas oliw gepalar."

and 
$result="Kapa[rand2]dim[mailingid]nen[rand2]ma[rand1]sibilol[rand1][mailingid]sebire [rand1]rola[rand2]lunie.Ifosamac[mailingid]rapieco[rand1]him[rand1][mailingid]oku,[rand1]vimeror[mailingid]eralerie[mailingid]puredus[hashx]elacecos[rand1]tusorop[rand1][mailingid]gobas[rand1]oliw[mailingid]gepalar."

where Randam values are "[mailingid],[rand1],[rand2],[hashx]"

please give me php code ....

Comment: "please give me php code ...." SO is here for advice on specific problems, not to do your job for you.

Comment: have a look [here](http://www.php.net/str_replace) for PHP code, and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to find out _what a good SO question_ should be, and lastly good ol' [whathaveyoutried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function `rand()` :

```
$str = str_replace(' ', rand(0, 10000), $str);
```

Or did you mean a random value from your list? In this case:

```
$list = array("value1", "value2");
$str = str_replace(' ', array_rand($list, 1), $str);
```

Comment: An Error occured with this...
"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE" in 
$list = array("value1", "value2");

please give me a proper solution

Answer (score 1):

Better use str_replace function.

```
str_replace(find,replace,string);

ex:- str_replace(' ','/',$string);
```